# Is there any way to grab the CSS truncated text via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to grab the HTML from a CSS truncated element and can't seem to get it right.

For example:

```
<span id=mySpan style=white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;width:50px>This is the contents of the span tag.  It should truncate with an ellipsis if it is longer than 50px.</span>
```

If I use the standard jQuery way to grab the HTML, I get the full text, not the truncated version.  I'm not sure if it is even possible.

```
html = jQuery('#mySpan').html();
text = jQuery('#mySpan').text();
```

Both return the full text.  I'm stumped.

Comment: overflow:hidden instead of overflow=hidden

Comment: you would have to calculate this yourself

Comment: The truncation is just an _visual effect_ which does not change anything actually. You will of course get the full text (in your DOM) through the `text()` or `html()` method.

Comment: The text are already set on the DOM, ellipsis are just use to styling

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777340/how-can-i-access-the-actual-text-that-is-displayed-in-a-div-when-using-css-style

Comment: Where the text truncates is likely to be different across browsers/OSes, any wherever you're putting the text should probably do the same thing (use overflow & ellipses), so what is the goal here?

Comment: @Izkata It may be different but it's still calculable as it is specified (see my answer).

Comment: @dystroy That's not what I meant.  I was wondering why Steve wants to do this, as it smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can compute it :

```
$.fn.renderedText = function(){
  var o = s = this.text();
  while (s.length && (this[0].scrollWidth>this.innerWidth())){
    s = s.slice(0,-1);
    this.text(s+"…");
  }
  this.text(o);
  return s;
}

var renderedText = $("#mySpan").renderedText(); // this is your visible string
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/tirosozimi/2/edit)

Of course this only works for an element with `overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis` but it's easy to adapt when there's no `text-overflow:ellipsis`: just remove the `+"…"`.

Note that this is compatible with all browsers and gives the exact result ([the w3.org specifies that the `…` character is to be used by the browser](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#text-overflow)).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great for me.  I couldn't really figure out how to type an ellipsis in VI, but I made it work for what I need it to do.

Comment: Use the compose key: `Compose + . + .` → …

Answer (score 8):

@dystroy has given a nice answer, here is another (more future-friendly) way to do this though.

We can use [`document.caretPositionFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/caretPositionFromPoint). This is almost a FF only function, but most other browsers provide the same thing under their own function name and API. No I don't know what browsers have against devs but oh well...

Our method works like this:

- select element
- get bounding client position
- put it in the above function to get text offset position
- subtract 3 from it to remove the ellipsis thingy from the offset
- extract text according to that offset from `textContent` property

Here is a quick demo (should work properly in Webkit and Gecko):

```js
function getRenderedText (el) {
  var pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var offset, range;
  if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(pos.right, pos.top);
    offset = range.endOffset - 3;
  }
  else if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
    range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(pos.right, pos.top);
    offset = range.offset - 3;
  }
  else {
    console.error('Your browser is not supported yet :(');
  }
  return el.textContent.slice(0, offset);
}

console.log(getRenderedText(el));
```

```css
span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span id="el">foo bar is so much awesome it is almost the bestest thing in the world. devs love foo bar. foo bar all the things!</span>
```

I have seen an error of maximum 1 character in some cases (weird fonts or edge cases), but most of the time, it works fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent answer, and doesn't thrash the DOM either!

Comment: To be clear, [`document.caretRangeFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/caretRangeFromPoint) works in Chrome (seen in the example).