# how to get visible lines from one div from other input and remove all other lines hidden by css

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue with generating an N number of lines of the full paragraph and put it into an input.

For that, I have created a code below

```js
$(".button_span").click(function(){
   $('.button_span').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
}); 
$(".event_button").click(function(){ 
    var count = $('#count').val();
    $(".event_button").removeClass('active_event');
    $(this).addClass('active_event');
    var selected_event = $('.active_event').attr("data-value");
    var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");
    
    if (selected_event == 'email') 
    {
        if ($(".button_span").hasClass("active")) 
        {
            var downloaddata = '';
            
            if (selected == 'lines') 
            {
                                                  
                var abc1 = $(".dummy").clone();
                abc1.removeAttr('style');                        
                downloaddata = abc1.html();
            }
            console.log(downloaddata);
            $('#data').val(downloaddata);
            
        }
    } 
}); 
$(".large_orange_button").click(function(){    
   var count = $('#count').val();                 
   var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");                  
   if (selected == 'lines') 
   {
       var words = "";
       var text = "";
       $( "p" ).each(function( index ) {
           words += ($( this ).text()).trim();
       });
       $( "#demo" ).empty();
       $('#demo').append('<div class="dummy" style="display: none;">'+words+'</div>');    
       $(".dummy").css({"overflow": "hidden", "text-overflow": "ellipsis", "display": "-webkit-box", "-webkit-line-clamp": count, "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical", "display": "-webkit-box"});
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="count" value="3" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" required="required">
<span data-value="lines" class="button btn button_span">Lines</span>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="ltr" style="max-height: none; display: none;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generate text-right"> <input type="submit" class="large_orange_button" value="Generate"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="">
<span data-value="email" class="button btn event_button email">Send via Email</span>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This is the code which I have created in which click on lines and generate it, then you will find a number of lines which you have entered from the paragraph which is working fine, but issue with when you click on send via email and put that line which you generated in the input it passes full paragraph not only lines which you generated. Can anybody...

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Comment: @chandukomati Thank you for your reply please run my put number in input 1,2 or 3 after that click on lines and click on generate it shows you N lines which you enter after that when you click on send via email then I need lines which you generate

Comment: @chandukomati but it is not working

Comment: but active class is not initiated. then why did you using this line.  $('.active').attr("data-value");   here selected  variable undefined. have you checked. your code

Comment: @chandukomati thank you for your reply .active class is initiated on lines span please check

Comment: @chandukomati actually I have put few portions of my code which is important and runnable so please take according to that

Comment: ok let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $.fn.renderedText = function(){
      var o = s = this.text();
      while (s.length && this[0].scrollHeight >  this.innerHeight()){
        s = s.slice(0,-1);
        this.text(s+"…");
      }
      this.text(o);
      return s;
    };

    $(".button_span").click(function(){
       $('.button_span').removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
    }); 
    $(".event_button").click(function(){ 
        var count = $('#count').val();
        $(".event_button").removeClass('active_event');
        $(this).addClass('active_event');
        var selected_event = $('.active_event').attr("data-value");
        var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");

        if (selected_event == 'email') 
        {
            if ($(".button_span").hasClass("active")) 
            {
                var downloaddata = '';

                if (selected == 'lines') 
                {


                    downloaddata = $('#dummy').renderedText();
                }
                console.log(downloaddata);
                $('#data').val(downloaddata);

            }
        } 
    }); 
    $(".large_orange_button").click(function(){    
       var count = $('#count').val();                 
       var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");                  
       if (selected == 'lines') 
       {
           var words = "";
           var text = "";
           $( "p" ).each(function( index ) {
               words += ($( this ).text()).trim();
           });
           $( "#demo" ).empty();
           $('#demo').append('<div id="dummy" style="display: none;">'+words+'</div>');    
           $("#dummy").css({"overflow": "hidden", "text-overflow": "ellipsis", "display": "-webkit-box", "-webkit-line-clamp": count, "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical", "display": "-webkit-box"});
       }
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="count" value="3" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" required="required">
<span data-value="lines" class="button btn button_span">Lines</span>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="ltr" style="max-height: none; display: none;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generate text-right"> <input type="submit" class="large_orange_button" value="Generate"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="">
<span data-value="email" class="button btn event_button email">Send via Email</span>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30327971/2796249)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".button_span").click(function(){
   $('.button_span').removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
}); 
$(".event_button").click(function(){ 
    var count = $('#count').val();
    $(".event_button").removeClass('active_event');
    $(this).addClass('active_event');
    var selected_event = $('.active_event').attr("data-value");
    var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");
    
    if (selected_event == 'email') 
    {
        if ($(".button_span").hasClass("active")) 
        {
            var downloaddata = '';
            
            if (selected == 'lines') 
            {
                                                  
                var abc1 = $(".dummy").clone();
                abc1.removeAttr('style');                        
                downloaddata = abc1.html();
            }
            console.log(downloaddata);
            $('#data').val(downloaddata);
            
        }
    } 
}); 
$(".large_orange_button").click(function(){    
   var count = $('#count').val();                 
   var selected = $('.active').attr("data-value");                  
   if (selected == 'lines') 
   {
       var words = "";
       var text = "";
       
       if($("#ltr > p").length >= count)
       {
          if($("#ltr > p").length >= count)
          {
             var ptag = (parseInt(count) - 1);
             words += $("p:eq("+ ptag +")").text()
          }
       }
      
       $( "#demo" ).empty();
       $('#demo').append('<div class="dummy" style="display: none;">'+words+'</div>');    
       $(".dummy").css({"overflow": "hidden", "text-overflow": "ellipsis", "display": "-webkit-box", "-webkit-line-clamp": count, "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical", "display": "-webkit-box"});
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="count" value="3" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" required="required">
<span data-value="lines" class="button btn button_span active">Lines</span>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="ltr" style="max-height: none; display: none;">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nisl tincidunt eget nullam non. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Senectus et netus et malesuada. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generate text-right"> <input type="submit" class="large_orange_button" value="Generate"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="">
<span data-value="email" class="button btn event_button email">Send via Email</span>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

check it bro.