# Transfer the overflowing content from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am checking a `div` for vertical overflow of content using this `JS` code:

```
if ($("#col1").prop('scrollHeight') > $("#col1").outerHeight() ) {
  alert("this element is overflowing !!");
}
else {
 alert("this element is not overflowing!!");
}
```

But how can I remove the content that is overflowing and transfer it to another `div`?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/appsoln/fnecb7mL/6/

```js
if ($("#div1").prop('scrollHeight') > $("#div1").outerHeight()) {
  alert("this element is overflowing !!");
} else {
  alert("this element is not overflowing!!");
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px;
}

#div1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">
    TEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENT TEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENT
  </div>
  <div id="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  I was only able to detect that the `div` is overflowing. Beyond that  getting the content that is overflowing is something I am not able to make any logic of. I don't know if there is any javascript function or library that can help me get the overflown content. I seriously have no idea where to start because I don't know if it is even possible.

Comment: But do you mean just that part of the content that is overflowing instead of the whole content in div1 right?

Comment: @Chumpocomon yes

Comment: Then somehow you would have to calculate which characters are in the *overflowing box (or square)*, which is `scrollHeight - innerHeight` high and just as wide as the parent. And sits at the bottom of the page. Then extract those characters from the `textContent` value and place them in the other div. There is no CSS option that does this, except for [CSS Multi-column Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns) but that does it in a horizontal fashion.

Comment: Another way would be to wrap each character inside your `div` elements in a `span` and use [IntersectionObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to see which of those `span` elements are in the *scroll viewport* of the div and which are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get started with such code:

```js
$.fn.renderedText = function(){
  var o = s = this.text();
  while (s.length && this[0].scrollHeight >  this.innerHeight()){
    s = s.slice(0,-1);
    this.text(s+"…");
  }
  this.text(o);
  return o.replace(s, "");
};

if ($("#div1").prop('scrollHeight') > $("#div1").outerHeight()) {
  $("#div2").html($('#div1').renderedText());
} else {
  alert("this element is not overflowing!!");
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px;
}

#div1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">
    TEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENT TEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENTTEST CONTENT
  </div>
  <div id="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30327971/2796249)

Comment: Wow. thank you so much. You saved me from headache. This is a good starting point. I will modify it further according to my requirements.