# detect text ellipsis with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div, which has the css to truncate the text for certain width. The text gets truncated with ellipsis. However the inner text is the same. For the testing purpose I would want to read the truncated ellipsis text. Can I get the truncated ellipsis text with js?

```
@media (max-width: 1129px) {
    #mydiv {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        max-width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this, you'd have to do it manually with JavaScript by:

1. Calculating the viewable width of the div
2. Take your text and remove any characters that would be outside of this width

It's also been discussed here [Get clamped (with ellipsis) textContent from textNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936263/get-clamped-with-ellipsis-textcontent-from-textnode)