# Css and js looking for a way to pass info from CSS display overflow none

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a method in Javascript that will take all the information that is hidden because of the div overflow and put just the Overflow information somewhere else, in this case into another div in another page. Thank you

Comment: Don't think so-- you're probably going to have to spin that up yourself, if its possible. Maybe look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777340/how-can-i-access-the-actual-text-that-is-displayed-in-a-div-when-using-css-style) for ideas...

Comment: Thank you alex Im going to work on this because this problem is intriguing me. Will